# Usage of none the worse

Tags: grammar, british-english, subcontinental-english

The sentence is

I was none the worse for abstaining from exercise.

Is the sentence grammatically correct? If yes , whats the meaning of this sentence in simpler terms

Comment: Exercise isn’t something abstained from, but neglected. Your sentence is grammatically correct, but a better-worded sentence would be, ‘I was none the worse for neglecting exercise.’

Comment: @MikeJones Neglect is effortless, abstinence is a challenge. I was told to abstain from exercise after my surgery. The two also have a different sense of degree.

Comment: @Phil Sweet: Your physician said 'abstain' as a lazy way of saying 'refrain from'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP statement is grammatically correct.

A google search for *none the worse* reveals [this definition](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/be-none-the-worse).

The example sentence *I was none the worse for abstaining from exercise* means that not undertaking exercise had no effect.

(Native English speaker and book editor)